# Cannot get image gallery in JQtouch to work

Tags: jquery, image, rss, jqtouch, image-gallery

I've hit a road block on jqt app. Its pretty much all built the
gallery is just refusing to work. Every jquery image gallery I try to
implement end up with the same result: Failed to Load Resource.

I've got a list of Images dynamically created from an RSS feed. The
structure is layed out like so:

```
<div id="galleria">
 <a href="Image1.jpg"> <img src="thumb1.jpg"></a>
 <a href="Image2.jpg"> <img src="thumb2.jpg"></a>
 <a href="Image3.jpg"> <img src="thumb3.jpg"></a>
</div

<script type="text/javascript">
// Load the classic theme
Galleria.loadTheme('galleria.classic.js');
// Initialize Galleria
$('#galleria').galleria();
</script>
```

I'm currently using galleria but the same thing happened with every
other gallery script I have tried(from Safari developer console):

Animation could not be found. Using slideleft:    jqtouch.js:104
Failed to load resource: image1.jpg

Comment: Is there a working version you can share? Sounds like a basic path issue with where the images are stored, but that seems too obvious. One small thing I noticed (I'm guessing this may be a result of your copy/paste): your closing **</div** is malformed - line 5, in your example.

Comment: Sorry - I just wrote that up quick as an example, its not copypasta. I uploaded a version for you at http://www.greenschoolsites.com/alpha3/index-touchgallery.html. View it in safari, choose one of the schools (try hilden grange) click save and then go to the galleries. The urls are all fine - I've checked and can display all then all fine - I just can't get them to work with jqeury.

Answer (score 0):

What gallery libraries have you tried? Have you come across the jQT photo extension (see the [demo](http://samshull.com/jqtouch-r148/demos/main/))?

Take a look at "Photo Gallery" and "Photo Gallery 2". If you just want to have photos and some captions, it should be fairly simple to set up:

```
jQT.generateGallery("pageID",
    [
    {src:"http://www.site.com/somepic.jpg"},
    {src:"pic1.jpg",caption:"Test Image 1"}
    ],
    {defaultIndex:1}
);
```

Remember to include the jQT photo extension files: `jqt.photo.js` and `jqt.photo.css`.

Comment: Thanks. I did come across this but couldn't get it to work. The demo doesn't seem to run in safari and its also discontinued- not sure its very compatabile with the jqt version i'm using(166). I will give another go though.
I tried a bunch of jquery image gallerys (Neteye Touch Gallery looks most promising). I suspect its because the images are not JSON they cannot be manipulated by jquery but not sure how to go about fixing it. I have multiple RSS feeds that are .asp files and I'm not sure I really 'get' JSON...